# Password Reset emails being marked as spam

Tags: email, mailserver

Hi hope everyone is well.

We have come across a bit on an issue when requesting the password reset emails to go out. The emails come from my own email address as I am the only admin, but our O365 mail filter is classing these as spam.

I would presume that this is because the mail server (Office 365) thinks that Civi is spoofing my email address.

Has anybody else come across this and if so, was there any way around this.

Thanks, Terry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of questions

- What CMS are you using?
- How do you have your outbound email set up?
- Are other emails getting marked as spam?
- When you view source of the email, are there any headers inserted by the receiving mail server that let you know why it was marked as spam?

Password reset emails are typically sent by the CMS, not CiviCRM and you will need to make appropriate changes there. Both Drupal ([smtp](https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp)) and WordPress ([WP Mail SMTP](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/)) have SMTP plugins/modules that allow you to use a 3rd party SMTP server to send email.